# Reading Text File into Array using Java generates Exception

Tags: java, file, text-files

Even though the file **Movie_db.txt** isn't empty, I get the following exception:

the text file consists of this:

> hank horror 20.0 18 1

```
public void syncDB(List<Movie> movieList) throws IOException {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Movie_db.txt");
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  try {
      String line = null;
      String title;
      String genre;
      double movieDuration;
      int ageRestriction;
      int id;
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {
          title = scanner.next();
          genre = scanner.next();
          movieDuration = scanner.nextDouble();
          ageRestriction = scanner.nextInt();
          id = scanner.nextInt();
          movieList.add(new Movie(title, genre, movieDuration, ageRestriction, id));
      }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("List is empty");
  }
}
```

Comment: please share the file content as well with exact name of the file.

Comment: The problem with your exception handling is that you print `List is empty` for _any_ exception which might happen in your code.  Use a debugger to find out the actual line which is causing the exception.

Comment: call `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block. and update the output.

Comment: How are you so sure that if the code fails it will be because the "List is empty"?

Comment: @SandeepPolamuri Im getting these errors from stacktrace: java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)

Comment: Also, share movie class. This helps people in reproducing the issue quickly.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati That is irrelevant to the problem

Comment: Why is that irrelevant? Anyone asking question should be sharing as much details as possible. Now someone trying to reproduce the issue will have to create that class which takes time

Comment: Because the problem is not related to the Movie class. OP is making a semantic mistake because he doesn't know the Scanner class.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your path is correct, there is a problem in your code. I'd change this line

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner("Movie_db.txt");
```

with this one

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(Paths.get("Movie_db.txt"));
```

The reason is that in your snippet the Scanner only reads the string "Movie_db.txt" and in the second snippet it recognizes as the path to file.

Read [Scanner documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.nio.file.Path-) for more info

Answer (score -1):

`genre = scan.next();` line is throwing exception because nothing is left to read from file now, which causes catch block to execute.

You are providing a string to Scanner which is a valid input for scanner. Hence, it never reads the file.

> Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("full_path_to_container_dir/Movie_db.txt"));

Please have a look at this blog on how to read from a file using scanner - https://www.java67.com/2012/11/how-to-read-file-in-java-using-scanner-example.html.